# url rewriting with htacess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a static website upon which I have performed CMS but when I added `.htaccess` file    for url rewriting its not working.
eg. `www.example.in/new/index.php` to `www.example.in/new/index`. there are about 50 pages in my website. what shall i do, i m completely lost. this is the first time i m using `.htaccess` file.

I have written:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?user=$1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^new/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ new/index.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^new/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ new/index.php?user=$1.
```

Comment: ok thanx for the reply let me check whether it works for me or not. reply you soon if it works thanx once again

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set 
    **AllowOverride All**
in your Apache config.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: thank you for the reply. lets hope it works fine otherwise please suggest me with other alternatives. thank you once again